# postgresql: exclude data based on other incomplete data

Tags: postgresql, filter, null

In this data - there are multiple DATA_ID values associated with time-series data. I am trying to exclude all data from any DATA_ID values that return a NULL value for USE for any timestamp value.

In other words, I only want to return DATA_ID values (and their data) if they have complete (not any NULL) values for all timestamp values.

### Sample query given below:

```
SELECT   
My.Table.DATA_ID,   
MY.Table.timestamp,   
My.Table.USE

FROM   
My.TABLE

WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2012-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-06-02 23:59:59'

-- Something here that says exclude all data from DATA_ID(s)
-- with any missing USE data,   i.e. USE=NULL

ORDER BY DATA_ID, timestamp
```

---

Comment: You really should include your schema and some sample data, so people aren't left guessing about the data. I am guessing that `DATA_ID` is a number of some kind, `timestamp` is a timestamp value, and `USE` is a ... what? Is that right? Or is `DATA_ID` actually an array or something? Also, your column names are very very poorly chosen; one is a SQL keyword `USE`, one is a SQL data type name `timestamp`. Please show the *real* table.

Comment: It'll really help if you edit your question to add some sample data and an example of your expected results.

Comment: Your question also contradicts its self. In the text you say you want to skip `data_id` values if they have non-null values for all timestamps. Then in the example you say you want to exclude all data from data_ids with missing `USE` values. These appear to be different things.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly and you want to exclude whole batches of samples (determined by equal data_id and timestamp) that contain a null value.

```
SELECT   
My.Table.DATA_ID,
MY.Table.timestamp,
My.Table.USE

FROM
My.TABLE o

WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2012-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-06-02 23:59:59'

and not exists (select 1 from my_table i
  where i.use is null
  and i.data_id = o.data_id
  and i.timestamp BETWEEN '2012-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-06-02 23:59:59')

ORDER BY DATA_ID, timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing to do is something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION missing_info(MY.TABLE) 
RETURNS BOOL 
LANGUAGE SQL AS
$$ select $1.use is null -- chain conditions together with or. 
   -- no from clause needed.  no where clause needed.
$$;
```

Then you can just add:

where (My.Table).missing_info is not true;

And as you need to change the logic as to what sorts of info is missing you can just change it in the function and everything still works.

This is the sort of encapsulation of derived information where ORDBMS's like PostgreSQL really shine.

Edit:  Re-reading your example, it looks like what you are looking for is the IS NULL operator.  However if you need to re-use some sort of logic, see the above example.  NULL never "equals" NULL (because we can't say whether two unknown values are the same).  But IS NULL tells you whether it is NULL or not.